# How to get last day of a given year with moment?

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

I can hard-code the last day of a year because anyway it will always be 31st December. There are many solutions using `date`, `js`, `jquery`. But I'm working on an Angular project and hence my code is in `typescript`. My tech lead wants me to do this using `moment`. I'm not supposed to hard-code any date. Is there any built-in method provided by `moment` to fetch the last day of a *given* year. And I'm saying *given* year because in my case *given* year is dynamic. It can change anytime. I'm using `endOf()` method. I'm getting error with custom year. I mean:

`const lastDayOfYear = moment().endOf('year')` is working fine, but:

`const lastDayOfYear = moment().endOf(2025)` is giving me this error:

> Argument of type '2025' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StartOf'

I also tried:

1. `const lastDayOfYear = moment().endOf("2025");`
2. `year=2025; const lastDayOfYear = moment().endOf(year);`

How will this method work? I've gone through the entire [Moment docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/). Or should I stick to `Date` of javascript. Something like this:

`new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 11, 31);`

Please provide a solution.

PS: I want last date of a given year in `MM-DD-YYYY` format only.

Comment: `const lastDayOfYear = moment().endOf('year') is working fine` Can you tell us what exactly `'year'` is in this context

Comment: @bhaskar, `year` is predefined constant by moment itself, which will always refer to the current year i.e. 2020. there are other parameters also you can pass. For eg. 'week', 'day', etc.

Comment: Don't think that is possible.. Because a constant in JS will not be passes as a string. Given the answer below, I think the endOf() function takes a string argument which defines what part of the date you need the `end` of..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well if you really wanted to work that out with moment instead of using `12-31-${year}` you could instead use:

```
moment([year]).endOf('year').format('MM-DD-YYYY')
```

Comment: If `year=2025`, output is:
> Date is: 12-31-4045

Comment: Edited @Tanzeel

Comment: Sir, this solution worked. I'm going to use this only. Can you please explain me a little because I'll have to justify and my tech lead may do cross questions. Hope you understand what i mean. :-)

Comment: No Sir, I don't need `+1`. So i removed it from there. And now I'm ready to push the code. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: No worries @Tanzeel! In case you need to justify, `moment([year])` sets the timestamp to the given year before `.endOf('year')` moves it to the end of the year and is then formatted by `.format('MM-DD-YYYY')`

Answer (score 3):

```
moment(date).endOf('year');
```

Where date is a Date somewhere in that year.

Comment: Give me 1 min. I'll try this and come back to you. :-)

Comment: One small request. I tried this solution and i'm getting this output: `Date is: 1609439399999`. Now how do I confirm its 31st dec 2020?

Comment: do a `new Date(1609439399999)`, which will return a formatted date object with that date.  I checked it, that timestamp gives Dec 31 of 2020.

Answer (score 1):

set current date in moment ***new Date()***

```
const now = moment(new Date()).endOf('year');
alert(now);
```

Comment: Your answer is also correct but the output is `1609439399999` while the format should be `MM-DD-YYYY`. Thanks anyway. I appreciate your time and efforts. :-)

Comment: so you can use this ***moment(new Date()).endOf('year').format("MM-DD-YYYY")***